# Chrome not raising resize event

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

If you look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/umjcd/4/

HTML:

```
<h1>Instructions</h1>
<ol>
    <li>Click on Resize Button</li>
    <li>Observe no resize event is raised</li>
    <li>Click on Check Height button</li>
    <li>Observe height has changed</li>
</ol>
<button id="button">Resize</button>
<button id="button2">Check Height</button>
<br/>
<div id="map" style="position:fixed;width:600px;height:0px;border:1px solid black;">
    <div id="root" style="position:absolute;left:0px;right:0px;top:0px;bottom:0px;border:1px solid red"/>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var button = document.getElementById('button');
button.addEventListener('click', process);

var root = document.getElementById('root');
root.addEventListener('resize', resize);

var console = document.getElementById('console');
var map = document.getElementById('map');

var button2 = document.getElementById('button2');
button2.addEventListener('click', function () {
    log(root.offsetHeight);
});
log('ready to log');

function process() {
    map.style.height = '400px';
}

function resize() {
    var w = root.offsetWidth;
    var h = root.offsetHeight;
    log('resize event raised, dimensions are ' + w + " x " + h);
}

function log(text) {
    console.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
    console.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
}
```

Chrome does not raise the `resize` event when the `div` is resized. **Is this a bug, or is this ok?** In IE and FF, `e.onresize` returns `undefined` but in Chrome `e.onresize` returns `null` where `e` is a HTML `div`. The intellisense in Chrome debugger detects a `onresize` property on `e`. Should it be returning `undefined` in chrome? IE and FF support `resize` but only on the `window` object. I cannot find proper documentation explaining when `resize` is supposed to be raised and whether non-`window` objects are supposed to support it or not in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

From the W3C Specification:

> A user agent must dispatch this event when a document view has been resized.

http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-resize

The `resize` event is fired when the window is resized, not any elements that you picked.

Comment: so then what's the point of chrome offering a resize event and then not raising it when an element is resized? as i say in my question, in IE and FF there is no onresize property on a div, but chrome does have a onresize property on a div.

Comment: All events are available to every element (in Chrome). But that doesn't mean that the browser will fire it. Take `<a>` for example. It has the event `onplay` and `onprogress`, but these two are both Media events, which will never get triggered on `<a>` but they are still there.